# subsetting elements of a list by elements of another list

Tags: r, list, subset

Let's assume I have a list of four data.frames containing some NA values:

```
my.list<-replicate(4,data.frame())
names(my.list)<-paste0("Frame.Number", c(1:4))
for (i in 1:4){
  my.list[[i]]<-mapply(rnorm,10,c(1:4))
  my.list[[i]][i+1,3]<-NA
  my.list[[i]][c(i,i*2),4]<-NA
}
```

For each of the data.frames, I want to select those rows which don't contain NAs in the 4th column. I can, for example, create a list of vectors (?) containing information about the completeliness of the cases in each data.frame:

```
selector <- lapply(my.list,"[",, 4)
selector <- lapply(selector,complete.cases)
```

Now this is where I am stuck: how do I apply the `selector` list to the `my.list` list in order to select only the complete cases? I thought I could use `lapply` again, but I cannot figure out some meaningful syntax.

Comment: `lapply(my.list, function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. the "reality" is somehow a bit more complicated: I will thus update my question.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was searching for. Seems so very easy, but it can be quite a pain to find something like that when you are not so familiar with R. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `lapply` over list, select the 4th column and get the index of non-NA values and subset the matrix accordingly.

```
lapply(my.list,function(x) x[!is.na(x[,4]), ])

#$Frame.Number1
#           [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,]  0.3668229  2.0688573 2.466580 4.339755
#[2,] -0.6391422  3.2635271 2.011809 3.296089
#[3,]  0.8662670  2.2797301 4.838563 4.443876
#[4,] -0.8972108  2.9305257 3.461650 5.525453
#[5,] -0.3452349 -0.2211153 2.570717 3.915671
#[6,]  0.6464616  2.3472838 4.009406 3.436188
#[7,]  0.9341354  2.3092428 2.338770 4.359324
#[8,] -0.5652311  3.2143472 1.944220 4.042566

#$Frame.Number2
#            [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,]  0.22304364 2.6085569 3.459335 2.575920
#[2,] -0.08987518 2.9515099       NA 3.775579
#[3,]  2.03265254 0.9405609 3.266783 4.009509
....
```